# preloader apears on navigation bar only

Tags: html, css

im using Leaflet.js on my HTML Page and also i have a navigation bar on the Leaflet map page.

as the leaflet library loads too late , i want to add a prelaoder on my HTML Page
but everytime when i try to add any preloader , the preloader only apears on my navigation bar

can you guys please help me?

here's the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%; margin:0;">
<head>

  <title> METAFARM WORLD </title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/loader1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/leaflet/leaflet.css">
  <script src="scripts/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/moralis-v1/dist/moralis.js"></script>
  <script
    src="https://github.com/WalletConnect/walletconnect-monorepo/releases/download/1.6.2/web3-provider.min.js"></script>


  </script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0;">


  <div class="loader">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>


   <div dir="rtl" style="display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;padding:0.3em;background-color:rgb(4, 24, 54);color:rgb(33, 191, 150);align-items:center">
    <button style="margin-right: 1rem;width:7rem;color:rgb(33, 191, 150);cursor:pointer;height:2rem;margin-left:1rem" id="btn-logout">Logout</button>
    <button style="width:7rem;color:rgb(33, 191, 150);cursor:pointer;height:2rem;margin-left:1rem" id="btn-login">Authenticate</button>
    <button
    onclick="window.open('https://mfarmgame.com/index.php/ico/metafarm-initial-coin-offering/')"
    style="margin-left:1rem;background-color:#1890ff;color:white; height:2rem;border:0;cursor:pointer;width:7rem;border-radius:0.2em"
  >
    Presale
  </button>
    <button
      onclick="window.open('https://marketplace.mfarmgame.com')"
      style="margin-left:1rem;background-color:#1890ff;color:white; height:2rem;border:0;cursor:pointer;width:7rem;border-radius:0.2em"
    >
      Marketplace
    </button>
    <button
    onclick="window.open('https://mfarmgame.com')"
    style="margin-left:1rem;background-color:#1890ff;color:white; height:2rem;border:0;cursor:pointer;width:7rem;border-radius:0.2em"
  >
    Home
  </button>
    <div
     style="padding:1em;border:1px solid black;border-radius:1em;background-color:rgb(51, 102, 102);margin-left:0.4rem" 
     id="div-wallet"
     >
    </div>
    <a style="margin-left:0.4rem" href="https://mfarmgame.com">
      <svg width="60" height="60" viewBox="0 0 183.33 183.33" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><polygon points="151.9,156.28 121.26,168.97 90.63,181.67 59.99,168.97 29.35,156.28 16.67,125.65 3.97,95.01 16.67,64.37 29.35,33.74 59.99,21.05 90.63,8.36 121.26,21.05 151.9,33.74 164.59,64.37 177.28,95.01 164.59,125.65 " fill="#009933"></polygon><polygon points="99.77,95.35 127.53,150.76 125.26,154.57 119.98,154.57 91.41,110.76 66.51,153.91 55.97,153.91 51.41,146.27 19.88,94.7 40.7,61.91 45.17,71.79 37.7,94.82 60.5,130.67 81.48,94.68 53.72,39.27 56,35.45 61.27,35.45 90.87,77.89 114.74,36.12 125.28,36.12 129.84,43.75 161.38,95.33 140.55,128.11 136.09,118.24 143.55,95.2 120.75,59.35 " fill="#ffffff"></polygon></svg>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #003333; margin: 0;"></div>
  





  <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  //initApp is getting called at end of file
    async function initApp() {
      // Declare Map Objects
      var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);

      //Refrence the tiles
      L.tileLayer('maps/16x162/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 6,
        continuousWorld: false,
        noWrap: true,
      }).addTo(map);





      //Load inventory
    let MY_INVENTORY = await loadInventory(); 

    //Start creating tiles
// LANDS Objects 
//a1------------------------------------------------------------

    var bounds = [[43.100983, 1.757813], [40.446947, -1.801758]];

    var rect1 = L.rectangle(
      bounds, 
      { 
        color: calculateColor(getInventoryItemById(MY_INVENTORY, 1 )),
        weight: 1.5 
      }
    ).addTo(map);

    var popup1 = metadataToPopup(getInventoryItemById(MY_INVENTORY, 1 ));
    rect1.bindPopup(popup1);

 //a2 ------------------------------------------------------------
    var bounds = [[48.04871, 1.757813], [43.100983, -5.405273]];
    var rect2 = L.rectangle(
      bounds, 
      { 
        color: calculateColor(getInventoryItemById(MY_INVENTORY,2)),
        weight: 1.5 
      }
    ).addTo(map);

    var popup2 = metadataToPopup(getInventoryItemById(MY_INVENTORY,2));
    rect2.bindPopup(popup2);


}
    initApp();

</body>


</html>
```

CSS :

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|ZCOOL+KuaiLe&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #f5f7fa 0%, #c3cfe2 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}




.main {
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
  }
  
  .main h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .main p {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #333;
  }
  
  .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background: purple;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  
  .btn:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  
  /* LOADER 1 */
  .loader {
    height: 50px;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    animation: rotate 3s linear infinite;
  }
  
  .circle {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: purple;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0);
    animation: grow 1.5s linear infinite;
    margin: -10px;
  }
  
  .circle:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: palevioletred;
    animation-delay: 0.75s;
  }
  
  @keyframes rotate {
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes grow {
    50% {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  }
```

JS :

```
const loader = document.querySelector('.loader');
const main = document.querySelector('.main');

function init() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    loader.style.opacity = 0;
    loader.style.display = 'none';

    main.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(() => (main.style.opacity = 1), 50);
  }, 1000);
}

init();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFtIK.jpg)

can anyone help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think the easiest way to add a preloader to the entire body is like this

```
body{
   position: relative;
}

.preloader{
   position: absolute;
   inset:0;
   z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: tried , not working